# Has any Buddhist meditator claimed that the mano-vijnana has a base to differentiate it from the other consciousnesses?

Tags: consciousness

Has any Buddhist meditator claimed that the [mano-vijnana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_Consciousnesses#The_eightfold_network_of_primary_consciousnesses) has a base (I don't mean that in any technical sense) to differentiate it from the other consciousnesses?

If so, what is it called, and when is its action suspended?

Comment: Could you edit the question to increase clarity regarding what kind of base we are talking about and what you mean when writing *"I don't mean that in any technical sense"*? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Theravada Abhidhamma Mental Consciousness (mano-vijnana) is heart based. This is what Buddha realised through his meditation. Other consciousness arise with the respective faculties and the base, e.g. eye-consciousness with the eye.

It is suspended when you are in Nirodha Samapathi and in Bavanga consciousness. Also perhaps in Pala Samanapathi if this result in a momentarily entering Nirodha Samapathi but not very sure on this as there are different view on this.

Answer (score 0):

In my limited and paltry understanding, the mano-vijnana or the "sixth sense according to the Buddha"  is [just] another sense-consciousness linked with a sense-gate.

That sense-gate is gateless.  Just like all your senses.

The gateless gate.

Streams.

Mind is the hub of these six streams -- the hub of a wheel is Mind and the six spokes are the different sense-consciousnesses.

All sense-consciousnesses can become "suspended" in penetrative insight and samadhi.  Your sense-consciousnesses get suspended when you sneeze or when you have an orgasm.  Even the "thinking" sense consciousness.

I hope that helps.

Anyway, these words, upon your realizing their meaning, will not be an accurate reflection of your understanding (they do not accord with the Ultimate truth) but perhaps they may be helpful in getting you closer to a breakthrough.